# Python: how to select rows based on delta time in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a datframe like the following:

df

```
          i   j      t_start_date_x        t_end_date_x      t_start_date_y     t_end_date_y
20149   491 191 2020-03-20 12:44:03 2020-03-20 16:03:57 2020-03-20 10:40:47 2020-03-20 17:12:14
20150   504 505 2020-03-20 12:54:14 2020-03-20 16:20:48 2020-03-20 16:39:59 2020-03-20 22:59:14
20151   505 504 2020-03-20 16:39:59 2020-03-20 22:59:14 2020-03-20 12:54:14 2020-03-20 16:20:48
20152   506 282 2020-03-20 10:39:35 2020-03-20 16:31:48 2020-03-20 15:24:32 2020-03-20 15:34:34
20153   515 494 2020-03-20 12:56:40 2020-03-20 18:58:15 2020-03-20 09:55:16 2020-03-20 15:31:22
```

I want to keep only the rows in which there is an overlap in time

```
          i   j      t_start_date_x        t_end_date_x      t_start_date_y     t_end_date_y
20149   491 191 2020-03-20 12:44:03 2020-03-20 16:03:57 2020-03-20 10:40:47 2020-03-20 17:12:14
20152   506 282 2020-03-20 10:39:35 2020-03-20 16:31:48 2020-03-20 15:24:32 2020-03-20 15:34:34
20153   515 494 2020-03-20 12:56:40 2020-03-20 18:58:15 2020-03-20 09:55:16 2020-03-20 15:31:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by checking if 't_start_date_x' is before 't_end_date_y' and the same inverting x and y like:

```
mask_overlap = ((df['t_start_date_x']<=df['t_end_date_y'])
               & (df['t_start_date_y']<=df['t_end_date_x']))
df_overlap = df[mask_overlap]
```

Comment: could I add also the time of the overlap?

Comment: @emax Probably with something like `df_overlap['overlap_time'] =  df_overlap[['t_end_date_x','t_end_date_y']].min(axis=1)-df_overlap[['t_start_date_x','t_start_date_y']].max(axis=1)`?